# Solving Double Equations

Tags: soft-question

So everyone knows (I hope) how to solve equations like $5x-2=4$ however how would you solve equations like $2x-1=3x-2=4x$. How, do you manipulate the equation? I've tried to use the common algebra rules however they don't work in these cases.

Comment: Well, look at what you wrote.  $2x-1=4x\implies 2x=-1\implies x=-\frac 12$.  But $3x-2=4x\implies x=-2$.  Thus, your system is inconsistent and there is no solution.

Comment: A string of equations like $a=b=c$ implies that $a=b$ and that $b=c$ as well as $a=c$, so the string of equations $2x-1=3x-2=4x$ can be rewritten as $\begin{cases}2x-1=3x-2\\2x-1=4x\\3x-2=4x\end{cases}$ (*the third line is technically unnecessary, but it doesn't hurt*).  From there you can rearrange terms to get the variables all on one side and the constants all on the other and then use standard techniques for solving a system of linear equations such as [gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).  As mentioned, your system in your example is inconsistent.

Comment: Basically, split it into two (or three, but the third is redundant) equations.